# GIT показывает текст commit'а в непонятной кодировке. Как исправить?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, git-push

Очень в странной кодировке выглядит коммит на сервере VPS, когда на локальной машине все ок. Push на Gitlab делаю с локальной машины через Git Bash. Как исправить?

**VPS**: Ubuntu 20.04

**Локальная машина**: Windows 10

[image: коммит]

Comment: Вангую неправильную локаль. Что показывает `locale -a` ?

Comment: И как вы ходите на vps

Comment: через git bash по ssh и хожу


en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: А так: `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 git log` ?

Comment: да, так корректно)) спасибо. а по умолчанию как сделать?

Comment: Настроить на vps эту локаль по умолчанию. Но для начала посмотреть а какая сейчас стоит. `env | grep LC_`